# Raphael + svgweb + svg core

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Can it be possible to use Raphael js with svg web and svg core (original SVG API), so that I can get the benefit of all available features? I tried to load them together, but nothing would happen. Perhaps they overwrite each other's functionalities.

More precisely, once again my question is can I apply Raphael js along with svgweb on a single SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried combining SVG libraries , the main problem is that they use their own canvas so one will always be on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they wouldn't just conflict with each other, but those libraries are also quite big so that's a lot of stuff to download for your visitors. Also think of the added burden for the browser which has to interpret all of the libs and hold them in memory, potentially making the browsing experience less snappy.

What exactly are you trying to achieve that can't be done with a single one of those libs?